# How to remove sub views from parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in ios and i am trying to add multiple child views programmatically on my parent class they are adding fine(here i am loading child views from background class)

But when i add second child view on my parent view class i want to remove first child view on my parent view class but it is not removing my code is below please help me some one

### My code:-

### child class:-

```
#import "MainView1.h"

@interface MainView1 ()

@end

@implementation MainView1

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)loadView1 :(UIView *)myview :(int)viewValue :(UIViewController*)VC
{
    UIView * firstview;
    UIView * secondview;

    if (viewValue == 1) {

    [firstview willRemoveSubview:myview];
    [secondview willRemoveSubview:myview];

    firstview =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 430)];
    [firstview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    UIButton *addProject=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    addProject = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    addProject.frame = CGRectMake(100, 285, 100, 18);
    addProject.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [addProject setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addProject addTarget:VC action:@selector(ProjectPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [firstview addSubview:addProject];
    [myview addSubview:firstview];

    }

    else {

    [firstview willRemoveSubview:myview];
    [secondview willRemoveSubview:myview];

    secondview =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 400)];
    [secondview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    UIButton *addProject1=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    addProject1 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    addProject1.frame = CGRectMake(200, 285, 100, 18);
    addProject1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [addProject1 setTitle:@"Show View1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addProject1 addTarget:VC action:@selector(ProjectPressed123:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [secondview addSubview:addProject1];
    [myview addSubview:secondview];

    }
}
```

### parent class:-

when i clicked on below ProjectPressed button action i want to add second child view on my parent view class, It's adding fine but first child view is not removed from parent view class

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MainView1.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MainView1 * m1 = [[MainView1 alloc]init];
    [m1 loadView1:self.view :1 :self];

}

- (void)ProjectPressed:(id)sender
{
    MainView1 * m1 = [[MainView1 alloc]init];
    [m1 loadView1:self.view :2 :self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[firstview removeFromSuperview]
[secondview removeFromSuperview]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try now

```
-(void)loadView1 :(UIView *)myview :(int)viewValue :(UIViewController*)VC
{
UIView * firstview;
UIView * secondview;

for (UIView *view in [myview subviews]) 
{
 [view removeFromSuperview];
}

if (viewValue == 1) {

firstview =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 430)];
[firstview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
UIButton *addProject=[[UIButton alloc]init];
addProject = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
addProject.frame = CGRectMake(100, 285, 100, 18);
addProject.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[addProject setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addProject addTarget:VC action:@selector(ProjectPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[firstview addSubview:addProject];
[myview addSubview:firstview];

}

else {

secondview =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 400)];
[secondview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
UIButton *addProject1=[[UIButton alloc]init];
addProject1 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
addProject1.frame = CGRectMake(200, 285, 100, 18);
addProject1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[addProject1 setTitle:@"Show View1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addProject1 addTarget:VC action:@selector(ProjectPressed123:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[secondview addSubview:addProject1];
[myview addSubview:secondview];

}
```

}

Comment: nice answer now my problem has been soloved